# AHK Always on Top not working for Windows File Explorer and other Windows system windows?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, explorer, hotkeys

I've been using an Alwaysontop AHK script to keep my windows on top of other windows.

Here's the code in question:

```
^SPACE:: Winset, Alwaysontop, , A ; ctrl + space
Return
~#!x::Suspend
```

It works perfectly for practically every window I use except Windows-based windows - things like File Explorer, Task Manager, etc...

How can I go about getting these windows to also work with the script?

I've used WinSpy to get information on specific Windows things before, but I'm not exactly sure what to look for here, or if there is a simpler solution that can force Windows-based windows to function with the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine here. Is that the whole script?

Comment: That's the whole script. Does it work on things like Task Manager for you? Perhaps I have some software that conflicts but I've tried closing out of most of the applications I have and still nothing. Works great for things like Notepad though, just not Task Manager and File Explorer windows (and similar windows).

Comment: Try adding [#UseHook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_UseHook.htm) on top.

Comment: Just tested it but doesn't appear to change anything.

Comment: Try also to [run the script as administrator](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs).

Comment: That works! Thanks. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: I have a software called [Clover](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/Clover-EJIE.shtml) that turns my File Explorer into a Chrome-like UI with tabs. The script doesn't seem to work specifically for the File Explorer when that software is running (but it works perfectly when the software is off/uninstalled). Any ideas on how I could get the script to work on File Explorer with the Clover software?

Comment: I updated the Clover software and now it works perfectly in File Explorer, too. Thanks for all the help. If you want to answer the question outside of the comments, I can go ahead and mark this as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AHK won't intercept the key presses in a program running with elevated privileges, unless the script itself is running this way:

```
#UseHook

; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

            RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===

; ctrl + space:
^SPACE:: Winset, Alwaysontop, , A

~#!x::Suspend
```

For more details read https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs.